# Vertical text (not in table)

Tags: vertical-alignment

For a book cover, I want to write the title vertically (like in Japanese, but using English text):

```
         T
T        I
H        T
I  I  M  L
S  S  Y  E
```

How do I do this without jumping through a host of `\vbox` and `\hbox`es?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}



\makeatletter
\protected\def\vvv#1{\leavevmode\bgroup\vbox\bgroup\xvvv#1\relax}

\def\xvvv{\afterassignment\xxvvv\let\tmp= }

\def\xxvvv{%
\ifx\tmp\@sptoken\egroup\ \vbox\bgroup\let\next\xvvv
\else\ifx\tmp\relax\egroup\egroup\let\next\relax
\else
%\hbox{\tmp}%original
\hbox to 1.1em{\hfill\tmp\hfill}% centred
\let\next\xvvv\fi\fi
\next}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\vvv{This is my title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @user3671 note I added an extra `\egroup` in the code (otherwise you get a warning about an unclosed group)

Comment: Is there some way of using \vvv directly in \maketitle?

Comment: It should just work: `\title{\vvv{This is my title}} \maketitle` works for me, but in practice the standard title layout is not designed for this so you'd want to use `titlepage` not `\maketitle` and position it by hand.

Comment: Works for regular book layout, but not for tufte-book, which I'm using. Too bad. Thanks anyways for this neat piece of coding, David.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The extra `\egroup` is not needed, if you remove the extra `\bgroup` after `\leavevmode`.

Comment: @user3671: It also works for `tufte-book`, if you define the macro as protected macro: `\protected\def\vvv#1{...}`

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek thanks I added `\protected` (by the way you can edit my answers any time:-) I left in the bgroup-egroup as I recall having a plan for them at the time, although they are not really doing much here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: BTW, the characters can be horizontally centered using something like `\hbox to 1.1em{\hfill\tmp\hfill}` instead of `\hbox{\tmp}`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek yes I wished afterwards I'd done that but the OP seemed happy and life rolled on so I didn't go back and edit it, I suppose I should since you've poked a finger at me...

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek done:-)

Answer (score 20):

Split the title at spaces, then each word at letters and build a `tabular` for each word. Then print all the tabulars so obtained:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

% variables
\seq_new:N \l_verttext_words_seq
\seq_new:N \l_verttext_singleword_seq
\seq_new:N \l_verttext_final_seq

% user level command
\NewDocumentCommand{\verticaltitle}{m}
 {
  {\huge\verttext_title:n { #1 }\par}
 }

% Inner function
\cs_new_protected:Npn \verttext_title:n #1
 {
  % clear the sequence holding the final result
  \seq_clear:N \l_verttext_final_seq
  % split the title at spaces
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_verttext_words_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  % from each word build a tabular
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_verttext_words_seq
   {
    % split the word into letters
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_verttext_singleword_seq { } { ##1 }
    % build the tabular for the single word
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l_verttext_final_seq
     {
      \exp_not:n { \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}} }
      \seq_use:Nnnn \l_verttext_singleword_seq { \\ } { \\ } { \\ } 
      \exp_not:n { \end{tabular} }
     }
   }
  % output the tabulars separated by a \qquad
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l_verttext_final_seq { \qquad } { \qquad } { \qquad }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\verticaltitle{THIS IS MY TITL{É}}

\end{document}
```

Note that special letter must be braced; not a big deal with a title. You may want to increase `\arraystretch` in case accented letters are used.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, egreg. I marked David's response correct because I tried it out first because it looked simpler.

Answer (score 13):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\Longstack{T H I S}
\Longstack{I S}
\Longstack{M Y}
\Longstack{T I T L E}
~~or~~
\Longstack{T H I S {}}
\Longstack{I S {} {} {}}
\Longstack{M Y {} {} {}}
\Longstack{T I T L E}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm. (I had to install stackengine.sty and readarray.sty). Many thanks.

Comment: I cannot use this latex code. ! LaTeX Error: File `stackengine.sty' not found.

Comment: @ThoLe Presumably your TeX system is older and doesn't have this package available.

Comment: @ThoLe You can download `stackengine` at http://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine .  It will work if you place the `.sty` file in your working directory.  However, you should find out where your local LaTeX installation directory is on your machine, so that you can properly install it.