# Top-down text in LaTeX

Tags: rotating

I'm trying to write top-down text along side a float. Some thing like this

```
S
O
M
E
-
T
E
X
T
```

I could find the `\rotatebox` and `tikz` draw along text routines, but they rotate the characters too.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122466/vertical-text-not-in-table/122471#122471

Comment: Could you be more precise about what you mean with "alongside a float"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a minimalist solution which requires separate characters with a space

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{1em}
B O N J O U R
~\\
H E L L O
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.99\textwidth}
l\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice trick.