# Simple vertical text in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

How do we write this title vertically in TikZ - similar to [vertical text (not in table)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122466/vertical-text-not-in-table)?:

```
         T
T        I
H        T
I  I  M  L
S  S  Y  E
```

Comment: Use an answer from the mentioned question, just place it in a `\node`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All credits goes to [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) and  [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbjorn-t)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\protected\def\vvv#1{\leavevmode\bgroup\vbox\bgroup\xvvv#1\relax}

\def\xvvv{\afterassignment\xxvvv\let\tmp= }

\def\xxvvv{%
\ifx\tmp\@sptoken\egroup\ \vbox\bgroup\let\next\xvvv
\else\ifx\tmp\relax\egroup\egroup\let\next\relax
\else
%\hbox{\tmp}%original
\hbox to 1.1em{\hfill\tmp\hfill}% centred
\let\next\xvvv\fi\fi
\next}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node at (0,0) {\vvv{THIS IS MY TITLE}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]