# How to make a book spine

Tags: vertical

I want to make a book spine (this book is using chinese), I try this way but it works , is there is a better way to make it? here is my mini code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setmainfont{SimSun}
\begin{document}
   \cleardoublepage
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \vspace*{4mm} 
  \begin{center}
       {

        \begin{minipage}{1em}
            \setstretch{1.1}
            \fontsize{16pt}{18pt}\selectfont 这是书脊的得实现
            \vskip 20mm
            还有另外的实现方法吗
        \end{minipage}
       }
     \end{center}
    \clearpage
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122466/80972