# How to write this text?

Tags: text-decorations

```
v
a
l
i
d
a
t
i
o
n
```

I need to write the word as vertically. I use overleaf.

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}v\\a\\l\\i\\d\\a\\t\\i\\o\\n\end{tabular}`

Comment: Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122466/21344 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shows the manual way. It also provides a macro, that eases the input of this, spaces would be ignored in the input of that word.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\verticalword[2][c]
  {%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}
      \verticalword@#2\verticalword@
    \end{tabular}
  }
\newcommand*\verticalword@[1]
  {%
    \ifx\verticalword@#1%
    \else
      #1\\
      \expandafter\verticalword@
    \fi
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  v\\a\\l\\i\\d\\a\\t\\i\\o\\n
\end{tabular}
\verticalword{validation}
\end{document}
```